# graphviz: node with edge to itself returns nullptr

Tags: graph, graphviz, graph-visualization

i am playing with CFGs and at one point i have a graph that has an edge to itself. IE it's a do-while loop.

```
loop:
...
ifeq ... goto loop;
```

Why, if i pass the same `Agnode_t` pointer to the `agedge()` as both head and tail, does the function simply fail and return a `nullptr`?

example code:

```
Agnode_t* n = ...;
Agedge_t* e = agedge(graph, n, n);
//e == null
```

edit: i am talking about the c-api. also corrected the function name.

Comment: What API are you talking about? The cgraph API for Graphviz doesn't have an `edgeadd()` function, as far as I know.

Comment: sorry, i corrected the function name. It's actually 'agedge()'. But yes, the C api.

Answer (score 0):

How do you create the graph? What version of GraphViz and what OS are you using?

A method that should work for all OS and Graphviz versions:

```
Agraph_t* g = agopen("g", Agdirected, 0);
```

This graph is non-strict and must allow "self-arcs" as it written in documentation:

> Strict graphs do not allow self arcs or multi-edges.

I tested it on Windows for GraphViz versions 2.38 and 7.1.0.
For v2.38 it works fine, **but for v7.1.0 it behaves as you described**.
In such a case, allow the creation of self-arcs (or loops) explicitly, setting **dir.no_loops = 0**:

```
    Agdesc_t dir;
    dir.directed = 1;   /* if edges are asymmetric */
    dir.strict = 1;     /* if multi-edges forbidden */
    
    //This flag
    dir.no_loop = 0;        /* if no loops */ 

    dir.maingraph = 1;  /* if this is the top level graph */
    dir.flatlock = 1;   /* if sets are flattened into lists in cdt */
    dir.no_write = 0;   /* if a temporary subgraph */
    dir.has_attrs = 1;  /* if string attr tables should be initialized */
    dir.has_cmpnd = 1;  /* if may contain collapsed nodes */

    g = agopen((char*)"g", dir, 0);
```